# Why is "implementational" not listed in dictionaries

Tags: word-usage

I just noticed that the word *implementational* is not listed in any of the major online dictionaries (such as Oxford or Merriam-Webster). Why is this word not listed and is it thus bad practice to use this word for e.g. scientific papers? Google shows over 120,000 [hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=implementational), many of those in scientific publications.

[Here](https://books.google.de/books?id=9GN-AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT53&lpg=PT53&dq=implementational&source=bl&ots=NdEqoTWGNL&sig=0aF0ytFcK8L4HyhXMOrrMzYstSU&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=implementational&f=false) is a book chapter that uses this word extensively.

Comment: What would be an example sentence?

Comment: @IsobellaPines That's why I put the google results. There are plenty of sample sentences.

Comment: @adjan Googling the internet is not a reliable reference. This is a new word that nobody ever used until recently, probably because it is ponderously long. Please see the Ngram record in print works. It does occur in scholarly texts but appears not to be found in fiction; make of that what you will.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because this is a brand new coinage that [nobody ever bothered us with](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=implementational&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimplementational%3B%2Cc0) until recently:

[image: ngram for implementational]

It’s also because no dictionary *ever* enumerates all possible words produced by applying **productive derivational suffixes** to base words. And few spellcheckers work that way, either, even though they should.

The scattered occurrences in the historical record do not yet justify wasting limited space for something everyone knows what means.

I strongly suggest checking [occurrences in Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=implementational&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C6&as_sdtp=) if you want to see acceptable scholarly uses of your term. Check other corpora as well; notice how [Google Ngrams reports **zero occurrences of *implementational*** in their English Fiction corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=implementational&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=16&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=).

Then again, the OED2 does attest to nearly two hundred words like it, many of which you surely have not yet encountered before. So I imagine they’ll eventually get around to yours, too. :)

Comment: I also noticed it is being marked as wrong in text-processors like MS Word. Why, if this is just a simple rule that can be checked?

Comment: @adjan Because few spell-checkers are smart enough to apply actual rules of productive affixes to determine is-a-word-ness blessing. Never, ever, ever trust automated spell-checkers to be smarter than actual humans.

Comment: Well, Word actually seems to be pretty smart, as it recognizes "nonsense" compound words in my native language, German. That's why I was so surprised. "base-word + suffix" is really easier to check than three words concatenated (the concatenation may even include declension and still be marked as correct)

Comment: @adjan It's more complicated than that, though. Not all "base-word + suffix" combinations are recognizable and correct, which is why a rule as simple as that is not accurate.

Comment: Do you mean grammatically or semantically correct? Because Word does really not care about the meaning, e.g. "Maussteckdosenheim" is correct, meaning "Home of the mouse power outlets". @Hank

Comment: @adjan I meant in reference to English. Not all suffixes can just be added to a base word and result in a recognized English word. Also, what is considered a base word? What makes *implementation* the base word instead of *implement* being the base? My point is, it's not as black and white as you suggest.